# Converting dollar sign notation to dot notation

Tags: haskell

How would I make the following into the same function with dot notation?

```
 print $ map (`elem` Emoji.table) keywords
```

Comment: You can think of a `$` effectively saying put everything after this in a set of brackets.

Comment: I've removed part of your question that was off-topic for this site (preferences and opinions vary a lot); the other half is not a great question in my opinion, but at least on-topic, so this way your question is less likely to get closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can transform the expression a little at a time:

```
print $ map (`elem` Emoji.table) keywords
print (map (`elem` Emoji.table) keywords)
(print . map (`elem` Emoji.table)) keywords
print . map (`elem` Emoji.table) $ keywords
```

When you have `f $ g x`, you have `f (g x)`, which means you have `(f . g) x` or `f . g $ x`. In the example above, where `f` is `print` and `g` is `map ('elem' Emoji.table)`, it doesn't seem like there is anything to win from expressing the composition using `.`, but it might be more readable in other cases.

For example, if you were writing a point-free function:

```
printWithEmojis :: Keywords -> IO ()
printWithEmojis keywords = print $ map (`elem` Emoji.table) keywords
```

then you could also [eta-reduce](https://wiki.haskell.org/Eta_conversion):

```
printWithEmojis :: Keywords -> IO ()
printWithEmojis = print . map (`elem` Emoji.table)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(print . map (`elem` Emoji.table)) keywords
```

I replaced the map operator and list to try it out and used

`(print . map (==1)) [1..2]`

and

`print $ map (==1) [1..2]`

The `$` operator adds brackets around everything that follows, e.g. `foo bar $ baz qux` is equivalent to `foo bar (baz qux)`

The `.` operator is shorthand for composition, e.g. `(f . g) x` is the same as `f (g x)`